# Rails Form, save nested_attributes with belongs_to association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form, nested-forms, nested-attributes

I'm having some troubles saving nested attributes with a `belongs_to` association.

I have a form to pass a new Order. In it I would like the `Customer` to confirm some of his infos. I'm able to display the current customer infos but am unable to save new ones.

For info I'm already building the form from the `current_customer`, the new order is saved for the `Customer` no probs. What I want is to update `Customers` info within the form for `Order`

Here is my app:

`#Order Model`

```
belongs_to :customer, inverse_of: :orders, validate: false
accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
```

`#Customer Model`

```
has_many :orders, inverse_of: :customer, dependent: :destroy
accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders
```

`#Order View new`

```
= simple_form_for @order, validate: true do |f|
    = f.association :customer do |c|
        = c.input :phone

        = c.input :mobile

        = c.input :skype
```

`#Order controller > #Strong parameters`

```
customer_attributes: [
  :id, :phone, :mobile, :skype
]
```

`#Order controller`

```
  def new
    @order = current_customer.orders.build
    render 'customers/orders/new'
  end

  def create
    @order = current_customer.orders.build order_params
    if @order.save
      flash[:notice] = t('order.create.flash.success')
      redirect_to customers_path
    else
      render 'customers/orders/new'
    end
   end
```

`#Order model > Validation`

This is a custom validation, since we ask the `Customer` to only confirm the field he choose.

```
%i(phone mobile skype).each do |kind|
      validate "#{kind}_validable".to_sym, if: "call_kind_#{kind}?".to_sym

      define_method "#{kind}_validable" do
        return unless !customer.nil? && customer.send(kind).blank?
        errors.add "customer.#{kind}".to_sym, I18n.t("activerecord.errors.models.customer.attributes.#{kind}.blank")
      end
    end


enumerize :call_kind,
              in: { phone: 0, mobile: 1, skype: 2 },
              predicates: { prefix: true },
              default: :mobile
```

Thanks for reading.

**My project:**

- Ruby On Rails 4.2.6 / Ruby 2.2.2
- Devise 3.5.9
- Simple form 3.1.0
- Enumerize 1.1.0